Snubber circuit for an electromagnetic brake
An electromagnetic brake is installed in an application and switched using a relay.
The switching relay failed, and upon analyzing the root cause, it was found that the snubber circuit was absent. In the supplier's datasheet, I found a circuit diagram in which a varistor and capacitor are connected in parallel with each other (refer to the image). In most cases, I have seen them connected in series.
Can I connect them as shown in the supplier's circuit diagram, meaning in parallel with each other?


Brake details: 24 VDC, 38 W
Switching relay: 12 V, 10 A with software switching
Varistor - S10K95
Capacitor - 0.47 µF


What inductance is the clutch (in open and closed states)?

A snubber is often made of a resistor and capacitor in series.
If you use an snubber with a resistor and capacitor in series, then you could also put a diode (or TVS) in parallel with the snubber.  The snubber slows the rise of the voltage spike from shutting off the inductor.  This gives the diode a bit more time to switch on.
The circuit recommended by the electromagnetic brake manufacturer is fine.  The exact values and ratings for the capacitor and the suppresor depend on the inductance of the brake.  That should be in the datasheet from the brake manufacturer.  In an ideal world, the manufacturer would include part values for the given example circuit in the datasheet.

I think I'd look into a TVS rather than a MOV.  MOVs are intended for infrequent events - they have a rated lifetime in number of events (depending on the current and duration of the events.)
